# How to write to a readonly sqlite file in UWP

Tags: sqlite, uwp

So i'm new to UWP, after finished the connect to sqlite [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/windows10_development/windows10_development_sqlite_database.html), I tinkering with the code a bit to try out new things. Instead of create and save sqlite file in local folder, i change the file directory to installed location, i created a folder "data" and add sqlite file in it. At this point you can figure it out what problem i ran in to. I can only read/select table but can't write/insert, delete, update records in database. I kind of expecting this problems and i known reasons for this. What i want to know is:

- Can i change the readonly sqlite file in installed location to read and write? If can please show me the way.
- Is it practical or a good idea to keep database file in installed location? Or better keep it in local folder.

Here're my code:

For the mainpage.xaml

```
<GridView x:Name="gridView" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,401,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="287" Width="1219">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Test" x:Name="templateGrid">
                <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel"  Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="stack2" Margin="20,20,0,0">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{x:Bind ID}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,112,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="132,112,0,0" FontSize="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="328"/>
    <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Add" Click="button2_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="516,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

For code behind:

```
SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        string path = Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "data", "librarydatatbase.db");
        conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);
        List<Test> Records = conn.Query<Test>(@"select * from Test");
        gridView.ItemsSource = Records;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Execute("insert into Test (Name) values (?)", textBox.Text.ToString());
        List<Test> Records = conn.Query<Test>(@"select * from Test");
        gridView.ItemsSource = Records;
    }
```

For sqlite:

```
create table Test
(
ID integer primary key autoincrement,
Name nvarchar(25)
);

insert into Test (Name) values ("Test value 1")
```

The error i received:

```
An exception of type 'SQLite.Net.SQLiteException' occurred in SQLite.Net.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: ReadOnly
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app's install directory is a read-only location (see [File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)). It is for application code and assets.

If you need write access to your database, you cannot place it in the app's install directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i known this already, i just wonder if there's a trick or a way around for this problem for database file.

Comment: @Dant: Security isn't implemented by locking the door, but leaving a key under the door mat. If you need a read/write database, store it in a location where you have read/write access. I don't know if this counts as a trick.