# UWP SQLite error: "attempt to write a read-only database"

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, uwp, runtime-error

im building an UWP application in Visual Studio 2019.
In this project i have created a database using DBBrowser.

I can read everything from this database without any problems but when i try to write some data to it, it gives me the error. (attempt to write a read-only database)

Can anyone help me with this issue, i've been working on this for hours and can't find a solution...
I've tried changing the security properties of the database. I've recreated the database etc.

[image: These are the properties of the database file]

[image: Here is the layout of the project files]

[image: Here is the code that i use to write the data to the database file]

Comment: Please consider snipping the images down to the relevant parts and add code as text. In general, add as text what _can_ be added as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP has very strict file access permissions.
I would suggest reading the [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) docs, and the following SO threads:

- [Including SQLite DB file with data in the UWP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340059/including-sqlite-db-file-with-data-in-the-uwp-application)
- [How to write to a readonly sqlite file in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41430350/how-to-write-to-a-readonly-sqlite-file-in-uwp)

TL;DR you should put your database in the `ApplicationData` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Where do i find the ApplicationData folder? I can not find it in the solution explorer.

Comment: @RikS It is a Windows folder: win+R -> %localappdata% -> Packages -> name of your app -> LocalState. You can access it in C# through `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`. See my first SO link for some reference code on how to move your db to this location.

Comment: Ah ok i get it. But i need to export the project when it's done to a teacher of mine. is that possible with this solution? Because the database needs to be exported with the project

Comment: @RikS If you are done with the database you can then just copy it back to the project, however it will then be read-only.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I copy the database from the assets folder to the ApplicationData folder now when you launch the app first time. It works!